# How to add question mark to .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like the link

`site.com/auth.php` to make accessible as`site.com/?auth=`

How should I proceed with this via .htacesss?

Comment: You should proceed by giving us your attempted code / research and by taking the [tour].

Comment: One usually go the other way around, using `.htaccess` to remove GET-parameters. What's your end goal here?

Answer (score 1):

Though this is a rather strange request, but here is what you actually ask for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^auth=$
RewriteRule ^/?$ /auth.php [END,QSD]
```

This would be a variant which is a bit more general towards the actual query string:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)auth=[^&]*(&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?$ /auth.php [END,QSD]
```

I doubt however that this really is what you want... Maybe you should invest a bit of effort to explaining what your goal is here?

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).